# View pictures in postman

Tags: postman, imageurl

Is it possible to preview images for the Image URL responses in postman? If postman doesnt have such settings, then is there any plugins as such for that? 
Otherwise, suggest some tool which can help do. This is very much needed for an application that I am developing, so please help.

Answer (score 11):

This can be achieved using the pm.visualizer option and then setting the template to use basic img src HTML in the "Test" tab.

Example;

Free API that returns an image URL:
https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random

```
const jsonData = pm.response.json().message
pm.visualizer.set(`
<body>
<img src="${jsonData}">
</body>`);
```

[image]

If you then click on the "Visualize" tab you'll see the image...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Postman V10.4.5. It works by default without any additional configuration.